# Can't play Hotstar Premium videos in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, video, flash

I am able to play non-premium videos using url-extracting extensions in chrome. But it is not working for Premium videos. Is there any solution?
      I have a premium hotstar account.